# How to Handle Back Button in Persistent Search Library

Tags: button, search, back, handle, persistent

In my App i am Using Navigation Drawer and **Persistent Search Library** in Action 
bar  https://github.com/KieronQuinn/PersistentSearch

So when i am in my Home Activity and Search View is not Shown and i press back Button

App is Exit Normally (No Issue)

But when Search View is Open and i Press back button there is an Exception Occurs

So i want to know how to handle Back Button In **Persistent Search Library**

Here is the Exception Details

[Exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EB9k.png) 
I figure out the way of handling this as

```
public void onBackPressed() {

DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (this.search.isActivated()) {
            closeSearch();
        }

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

But Same Exception Occures

Any help will be Appreciated

Comment: I am also getting same problem, i am able to get event for back press but not able to handle that exception as in this library class we have to change the value of "searchOpen" variable inside SearchBox class for resolving that error but it is private field inside class so unable to change

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your activity to handle backpress event for search view

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 4 && binding.appBrLt.searchbox.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            //here write the code
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
        }
    }
```